# Reduce array a array de objetos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, array-bidimensional

Tengo este array:

```
var miArray = [
    {  sku: "A", price: "red" },
    {  sku: "B", price: "blue"},
    {  sku: "A",  price: "green"},
    {  sku: "C", price: "black"},
    {  sku: "C", price: "blue" }
];
```

Y estoy creando una funcion para ordenarlos en un array de objetos por sku y cantidad, (no importa el precio) asi:

```
[
    { sku: "A", quantity: 2},
    {  sku: "B",  quantity: 1},
    { sku: "C", quantity: 2}
]
```

Esta es mi función reductora:

```js
var miArray = [{
    sku: "A",
    price: "red"
  },
  {
    sku: "B",
    price: "blue"
  },
  {
    sku: "A",
    price: "green"
  },
  {
    sku: "C",
    price: "black"
  },
  {
    sku: "C",
    price: "blue"
  }
];



function itemColor(data) {
  let group_to_values = data.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.sku] = obj[item.sku] || 0;
    obj[item.sku] += 1;
    return obj;
  }, {});
  return [group_to_values];
}

console.log(itemColor(miArray));
```

Creo que estoy cerca, ya que me entrega esto: `[ { A: 2, B: 1, C: 2 } ]` en vez de esto `[ { A: 2}, {B: 1}, {C: 2 } ]` que es lo que busco.

Pero lo que necesito es un array con los objetos independientes.

¿Cómo se puede crear esto desde la misma función reduce?

Comment: FranAcuna ya está agregado... es el array de objetos con sku y cantidades. [
    { sku: "A", quantity: 2},
    {  sku: "B",  quantity: 1},
    { sku: "C", quantity: 2}
]
Osea, lo mismo que ya tengo, pero en objetos independientes, no como está ahora en el mismo objeto.

Comment: ¡Tienes razón! Ignora mi comentario

Comment: El método [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) no devuelve un `Array`, por lo cual no es posible hacerlo sólo usando `reduce`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, en `reduce()` puedes definir el acumulador (valor a devolver) con el tipo de dato que prefieras, aunque parece que en este caso es como _[buscarle 3 pies al gato](http://blog.spanishcourseinspain.com/buscarle-tres-pies-al-gato/)_.

Comment: @MauricioContreras de acuerdo con triby, reduce si puede devolver un array, agregandolo como valor inicial sin problemas. Me basé en este video, por si alguien quiere concer el método (se ve muy simple en el video, pero estoy de acuerdo que puede no ser el metodo ideal para esto) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DMolJ2FrNY&t=666s

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de `reduce()` va a ser complicado crear un arreglo de objetos, supongo que implicaría agregar otro ciclo y tengo la leve sospecha de que sería mejor armar el resultado deseado por fuera.

```js
var miArray = [{
    sku: "A",
    price: "red"
  },
  {
    sku: "B",
    price: "blue"
  },
  {
    sku: "A",
    price: "green"
  },
  {
    sku: "C",
    price: "black"
  },
  {
    sku: "C",
    price: "blue"
  }
];


function itemColor(data) {
  let group_to_values = data.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.sku] = obj[item.sku] || 0;
    obj[item.sku] += 1;
    return obj;
  }, {});
  // Crear arreglo
  let ret = [];
  // Recorrer por clave para insertar objetos separados en arreglo
  Object.keys(group_to_values).forEach(key => ret.push({
    sku:key,
    quantity:group_to_values[key] }));
  return ret;
}

console.log(itemColor(miArray));
```

No creo que sea lo óptimo, pero con el método [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/findIndex) se puede verificar si ya existe el objeto dentro del arreglo:

```js
var miArray = [{
    sku: "A",
    price: "red"
  },
  {
    sku: "B",
    price: "blue"
  },
  {
    sku: "A",
    price: "green"
  },
  {
    sku: "C",
    price: "black"
  },
  {
    sku: "C",
    price: "blue"
  }
];


function itemColor(data) {
  let group_to_values = data.reduce((obj, item) => {
    // Buscar elemento en arreglo y obtener posición
    let found = obj.findIndex(existe => existe.sku == item.sku);
    if(found < 0) {
        // No existe todavía en el arreglo
        obj.push({sku:item.sku, quantity: 1});
    } else {
        // Sí existe, incrementar
        obj[found].quantity ++;
    }
    return obj;
  }, []); // El valor inicial es un arreglo, no objeto
  return group_to_values;
}

console.log(itemColor(miArray));
```

Comment: Gracias! Es muy buena respuesta, pero estoy seguro que se puede hacer en el mismo método reduce, que es lo que quisiera aprender :)

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, no es tan difícil.

Comment: @FelipeQuintana Creo que estás tratando de comer una sopa con un cuchillo.

Comment: @FranAcuna puede ser... como lo harías? no llevo mucho programando y menos en JS... En Ruby lo hubiera hecho con map transform sin gran problema, pero leí que así era en JS, ya que map no funciona para Objects (hashes en ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la función `reducer` en JS no pretende cumplir la función que especificas, en tu ejemplo estás utilizándola más que todo para iterar sobre el array. Sin embargo me parece muy interesante cómo lo haces, viéndolo bien usar reducer te ahorra tener que definir un objeto donde guardar los resultados.

Respondiendo a tu comentario en la otra pregunta: Simplemente iteraría sobre el array, puedes usar un `for` o un `forEach`, la lógica es casi idéntica a la que ya tienes, lo que le estoy agregando es la conversión al final de un objeto de con propiedades a un array de objetos que separen cada propiedad. Estoy consciente de que no es la solución más elegante.

```js
var miArray = [{
    sku: "A",
    price: "red"
  },
  {
    sku: "B",
    price: "blue"
  },
  {
    sku: "A",
    price: "green"
  },
  {
    sku: "C",
    price: "black"
  },
  {
    sku: "C",
    price: "blue"
  }
];



function itemColor(data) {
  let conteo = {};
  data.forEach(({sku}) => {
    conteo[sku] = conteo[sku]+1 || 1 ;
  });
  return Object.keys(conteo).map( e=>({[e]:conteo[e]}));
}

console.log(itemColor(miArray));
```

Usando el `reducer` con tú código:

```js
var miArray = [{
    sku: "A",
    price: "red"
  },
  {
    sku: "B",
    price: "blue"
  },
  {
    sku: "A",
    price: "green"
  },
  {
    sku: "C",
    price: "black"
  },
  {
    sku: "C",
    price: "blue"
  }
];



function itemColor(data) {
  let group_to_values = data.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.sku] = obj[item.sku] || 0;
    obj[item.sku] += 1;
    return obj;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(group_to_values).map(e => ({
    [e]: group_to_values[e]
  }));
}

console.log(itemColor(miArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto es lo que buscas. No me queda claro en tu pregunta si quieres que sea como `[ { A: 2 }, { B: 1}, { C: 2 } ]` o `[ { sku: 'A', quantity: 2 }, { sku: 'B', quantity: 1 }, { sku: 'C', quantity: 2 }, ]`

```js
var miArray = [
    {  sku: "A", price: "red" },
    {  sku: "B", price: "blue"},
    {  sku: "A",  price: "green"},
    {  sku: "C", price: "black"},
    {  sku: "C", price: "blue" }
];

const reducido = miArray.reduce((nuevoArray, elemento) => {
  const yaEnArray = nuevoArray.find(({ sku }) => sku === elemento.sku);

  if (yaEnArray) {
    yaEnArray.quantity++;
  }
  else {
    nuevoArray.push({ sku: elemento.sku, quantity: 1 });
  }
  
  return nuevoArray;
}, []);

console.log(reducido);
```

En la función `reduce` buscas si ya existe un elemento con ese `sku`, si existe, aumentas `quantity` de dicho elemento, si no existe, lo creas nuevo.